# how can I set up an internal network?

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, ethernet, dhcp

I have an IP camera with an Ethernet port connected to a computer. The camera is on a patch Ethernet cord to the Ethernet port, and the PC is on the Internet via a wireless device. I do not want to share the wifi with the camera, rather, I have an NGINx web-server I would like to send an image stream to. (I can handle that, provided I get the networking issues figured out.)

I have tried reading some tutorials such as this one: [Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP)](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dhcp.html)

DHCP server still fails to start on boot though.

```
Here is my current configuration:
# dhcpd.conf

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
authoritative;

# A slightly different configuration for an internal subnet.
subnet 192.168.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  pool {
    range 192.168.42.10 192.168.42.50;
  }
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
  option domain-name "local";
}

host rear_camera {
  hardware ethernet C4:D6:55:3E:4E:72;
fixed-address 192.168.42.15; 
   option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
}
```

when I try to start the service manually, this is what I get.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart isc-dhcp-server.service
Job for isc-dhcp-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

so then I look at `journal -xe`
which has this:

```
Sep 23 04:34:43 linux dhclient[2472]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Sep 23 04:34:44 linux NetworkManager[489]: <warn>  [1506141284.6473] dhcp4 (eth0): request timed out
Sep 23 04:34:44 linux NetworkManager[489]: <info>  [1506141284.6479] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed unknown -> timeout
Sep 23 04:34:44 linux NetworkManager[489]: <info>  [1506141284.7137] dhcp4 (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 2472
Sep 23 04:34:44 linux NetworkManager[489]: <info>  [1506141284.7138] dhcp4 (eth0): state changed timeout -> done
Sep 23 04:34:44 linux NetworkManager[489]: <info>  [1506141284.7146] device (eth0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavail
Sep 23 04:34:44 linux NetworkManager[489]: <warn>  [1506141284.7159] device (eth0): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
Sep 23 04:34:44 linux NetworkManager[489]: <info>  [1506141284.7177] device (eth0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30
Sep 23 04:34:44 linux NetworkManager[489]: <info>  [1506141284.7439] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1'
Sep 23 04:34:44 linux NetworkManager[489]: <info>  [1506141284.7504] device (eth0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (ccebad
Sep 23 04:34:44 linux NetworkManager[489]: <info>  [1506141284.7525] device (eth0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40
Sep 23 04:34:44 linux NetworkManager[489]: <info>  [1506141284.7590] device (eth0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Sep 23 04:34:44 linux NetworkManager[489]: <info>  [1506141284.7641] device (eth0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Sep 23 04:34:44 linux NetworkManager[489]: <info>  [1506141284.7664] dhcp4 (eth0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Sep 23 04:34:44 linux NetworkManager[489]: <info>  [1506141284.7710] dhcp4 (eth0): dhclient started with pid 2503
Sep 23 04:34:44 linux dhclient[2503]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
Sep 23 04:34:45 linux systemd-networkd[230]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Sep 23 04:34:50 linux dhclient[2503]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
Sep 23 04:34:55 linux systemd-networkd[230]: eth0: Lost carrier
Sep 23 04:34:55 linux kernel: rk_gmac-dwmac ff290000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
Sep 23 04:34:56 linux NetworkManager[489]: <info>  [1506141296.3183] device (eth0): link connected
Sep 23 04:34:56 linux kernel: setLedConfiguration: #### before setting led, Reg26 = 0x91 , Reg28 = 0x9200
Sep 23 04:34:56 linux kernel: setLedConfiguration: #### after setting led, Reg26 = 0x91 , Reg28 = 0x9200
Sep 23 04:34:56 linux kernel: rk_gmac-dwmac ff290000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
Sep 23 04:34:56 linux systemd-networkd[230]: eth0: Gained carrier
Sep 23 04:34:57 linux dhclient[2503]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
```

I have tried setting the interface in the file `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`
 with: 
`INTERFACES="eth0"`

This doesn't help.
I'm not sure what else to do. Please assist me in setting this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after all day of getting owned by this nonsense, I finaly figured out what is wrong (I guess).

I tried the cross over cable, but Im not using it now. I also review the logs of systemctl, and syslog to no avail. What it ended up being was a miss-configured `/etc/network/interfaces` file.
the original simply read:

```
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

Please note, prior to inspecting the /etc/network/interfaces file, I had tried turning eth0 on and off with `ifup` and `ifdown`.

I took a look at the same file on some other linux machines, and modified the file to reflect networking options I had set up on the dysfunctional computer.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.42
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.0.0.0
    broadcast 10.0.0.255
    gateway 10.0.0.1
    dns-nameservers 10.0.0.1 8.8.8.8
```

after making these changes, I did `sudo ifdown` eth0, `sudo ifup eth0` then `sudo service isc-dhcp-server start` The service started without errors.

I can now attach to my IP camera, and to my wireless network.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things that come to mind.

1. You did not set a static IP on `eth0` within that subnet that you are setting DHCP for.
2. You are connecting the camera *directly* to your PC with a regular **Straight-Through** cable instead of a **Crossover** cable.

[image]

The tutorial you linked is pretty straight forward but it would help more to post your configuration of `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` as it would help a lot.

If you can start your DHCP service again and when it fails, immediately run `sudo tail -n 50 /var/log/syslog` as well as `sudo systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service`, whichever one works and post the results.

Usually reading through `syslog` or the output of `systemctl status` will tell you exactly what is wrong rather than logging the activity that `journal -xe` provides.

This issue could be as simple as a missing semi-colon or a bad indention on a new line and maybe even a closing bracket `}`.

Comment: I was thinking that the modern ethernet sensing chip could handle this connection, without a crossover cable.  I think I wll try making an X-cable. 
I will post some logs, I have tried numerous configurations in the last few hours.  If I miss a semicolon, I get a message about it when I try to restart the service.

Comment: Gigabit Ethernet Is the one that is "smart" to not need a cross over cable. If at least one of the devices is using fast Ethernet, you still need one. If both are gigabit then it doesn't matter.

Comment: The attached device might not be a gigabit, so I made a cross over cable, but it is still not working.

Comment: does `syslog` have any errors? What about `systemctl`? Also, if this camera has a webui, what you could do it connect it to a regular router that has DHCP, gain access to the UI and see if you can manually set settings to match your DHCP scope, connect it back to your server and try pinging the camera. Also, confirm you have a static IP set in `/etc/network/interfaces`. This way both devices are set to static and you can rule out DHCP. After all this will be the only device connected to your server so there is no need for DHCP in the first place.